# Contact Form 7 - Error on activation Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm trying to activate Contact Form 7 on a WordPress website I have, but I got this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in /web/htdocs/www.mywebsite.it/home/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/l10n.php on line 123

Which should be this line:

[image]

How can I fix it?

I'm on 4.9.9 and PHP 5.5.38 (old site).

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Looks like you try to use some incompatible PHP syntax

Comment: @NicoHaase I just do "install" from admin panel. Everythings has been setup automatically...

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If you do "install", how is this problem even related to programming? Which PHP version do you use? Also, which version of Contact Form 7 do you try to install?

Comment: Also, Wordpress 4.9.9 is more than four years old. I don't want to guess how many unfixed security issues it contains

Comment: Added the PHP version. Can't update unfortunately (for some reasons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippet you've shared was introduced in Contact Form 7 v5.7 (according to the [commit from Github](https://github.com/takayukister/contact-form-7/commit/c656d0ca2a41c704714905c779483186c93d03c8)) which requires Wordpress 6 (according to [their release notes](https://contactform7.com/2022/12/10/contact-form-7-57/)).

I would recommend to update that Wordpress installation as soon as possible, as both PHP and Wordpress are horribly outdated. Also, your installation process looks completely broken if it allows to install incompatible plugins

Comment: I see, thanks! The only way is to install manually the 4.9.x version. I'm afraid to update Wordpress (what if it crash the actual plugins/theme which is not updated anymore?)

Comment: Having a vulnerable installation of Wordpress sounds like a worse idea to me. But anyways, this is not a programming-related question, and thus off-topic on StackOverflow.